# ¿Hay un código ascii o Unicode para los números con una línea superior?

Tags: ascii

Necesito incluir este símbolo en una aplicación Android.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe un código ascii o Unicode para números con línea superior?

Comment: Me suena más Unicode y no ASCII

Comment: Recuerda que las preguntas deben ser sobre un problema específico. Tu duda bien podrías haberla resuelto con una búsqueda en la red. Por ejemplo: [overline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline)

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras estuve realizando varias búsquedas sobre ascii y luego Unicode, pero no se me ocurrió que podría ser un atributo de html. Con eso tengo para representar el caracter, gracias.